# Mobile Chrome Browser - "Tab" to Select Element in Form When Pressing Next Button

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile

I'm developing a simple HTML form for a responsive web app that has the following form elements, listed in order of the markup.

1. Input
2. Select
3. Select
4. Input
5. Submit Button

When tabbing through the form in a browser on a computer, focus goes to the correct element in the order listed.

Using mobile chrome on a phone, clicking the "Next" button from the first input skips over the 2 select elements and focuses the second input.  Clicking the "Next" button from the second input attempts to submit the form.

Things I've tried:

- Adding required HTML5 validation attributes to the select elements.
- Adding empty options to the select elements
- Adding explicit tabindex attributes to all of the elements